# Problems opening files in Windows that aren't saved to the desktop

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

I am writing a program which needs to open and access the contents of 110 different text files, which I have stored in various folders and sub-folders on my computer (which is running Windows 7). I've defined variables for all of my files within the program, as follows:

```
#Arno Holz, Buch der Zeit 1886, 1892
Holz_raw = r"C:\Users\Carolyn\Desktop\Dissertation Texts (txt)\Poetry\1850-1900    (txt)\Arno Holz.txt"
Holz = open(Holz_raw, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()

#Felix Dahn, Balladen 1878
Dahn_raw = r'C:\Users\Carolyn\Desktop\Dissertation Texts\Poetry\1850-1900 (txt)\Felix Dahn.txt'
Dahn = open(Dahn_raw, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

...  and so on.

When I try to run the program, however, I get a message that says "no such file or directory".

Strangely, it works when I type

```
open(r'C:\Users\Carolyn\Desktop\Dissertation Texts\Poetry\1850-1900 (txt)\Felix Dahn.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

into the interpreter.

It also works when I save the file to my desktop directly and then supply that path as the first argument to open() within my program. (This works in the interpreter, too).

Do I need to save all 110 files to my desktop to get Python to recognize them? Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

I have looked all over the internet and haven't been able to find an answer. I've also spent hours and hours poring over various Python manuals...

I'd be grateful for any assistance you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the problem, and fixed it. The file paths for the two types of file are indeed different; not sure what happened there! Also, a friend recommended that I change the current working directory in IDLE, which it hadn't occurred to me to do. Did that -- problem solved!